Small section of code in my PS script returning an error
The code below is a section of a PS script I'm writing. Everything works except a small section that I copied as the script function is new for me. The section below is embedded in a menu.
The line "$whatIfResult = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& $args[0] -WhatIf} -ArgumentList $command
", specifically "{& $args[0] -WhatIf}" is returning the error:
"*The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or
a CommandInfo object.
At line:25 char:53

...      $whatIfResult = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { & $args[0] -WhatIf ...

CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadExpression*"



Full section is shown below.
     {
        $requiredColumns = "Zone","Computer","HostName","Name","TimeToLive"

        $csvPath = Read-Host "Enter full path to CSV file"

        $csv = Import-Csv $csvPath
            $missingColumns = $requiredColumns | Where-Object {$_ -notin $csv[0].PSObject.Properties.Name}

            if($missingColumns.Count -gt 0){
                Write-Output "The following required columns are missing from csv: $missingColumns"
            } else {
                Write-Output "All required columns are present in the csv file."
            }

        foreach ($record in $csv) {
            $zoneName = $record.Zone
            $computer = $record.Computer
            $NewHostName = $record.HostName
            $Name = $record.Name
            $ttl = $record.TimeToLive

        # Add the new PTR record with whatif and confirm changes
        $command = Add-DnsServerResourceRecordPtr -ComputerName $computer -ZoneName $zoneName -AllowUpdateAny -TimeToLive $ttl -AgeRecord -Name $Name -PtrDomainName $NewHostName

        # Run the command with -WhatIf
        $whatIfResult = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& $args[0] -WhatIf} -ArgumentList $command

        # Prompt for confirmation
        if ($whatIfResult) {
            $confirmation = Read-Host -Prompt "Do you want to apply these changes? (y/n)"
                if ($confirmation -eq "y") {
                    # Execute the command without -WhatIf
                    Invoke-Expression $command
                    Write-Host "Changes applied."
                } else {
                    Write-Host "Changes not applied."
                }
            }
        }
        Write-Host "Option 1 selected"
    }

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Wrap your "command" in double quotes ".

I think I see what you're trying to achieve there, but I think your problem is that the code doesn't do what you're perhaps expecting it to. The line :
# Add the new PTR record with whatif and confirm changes
$command = Add-DnsServerResourceRecordPtr -ComputerName $computer -ZoneName $zoneName -AllowUpdateAny -TimeToLive $ttl -AgeRecord -Name $Name -PtrDomainName $NewHostName

doesn't assign that command to $command so it can be run later, it runs it immediately and assigns any output from that command to the variable.
Your easiest option is to get rid of most of that chunk of code, and replace it with this simplified version :
Add-DnsServerResourceRecordPtr -ComputerName $computer -ZoneName $zoneName -AllowUpdateAny -TimeToLive $ttl -AgeRecord -Name $Name -PtrDomainName $NewHostName -WhatIf
$confirmation = Read-Host -Prompt "Do you want to apply these changes? (y/n)"
if ($confirmation -eq "y") {
    # Execute the command without -WhatIf
    Add-DnsServerResourceRecordPtr -ComputerName $computer -ZoneName $zoneName -AllowUpdateAny -TimeToLive $ttl -AgeRecord -Name $Name -PtrDomainName $NewHostName
    Write-Host "Changes applied."
} else {
    Write-Host "Changes not applied."
}

You obviously end up with the Add-DnsServerResourceRecordPtr line written out twice, but since you're programmatically generating all the parameters anyway I don't think it's the end of the world.
Update - altered version showing all THEN seeking confirmation.
foreach ($record in $csv) {
    $zoneName = $record.Zone
    $computer = $record.Computer
    $NewHostName = $record.HostName
    $Name = $record.Name
    $ttl = $record.TimeToLive

    # Show the whatif for each record
    Add-DnsServerResourceRecordPtr -ComputerName $computer -ZoneName $zoneName -AllowUpdateAny -TimeToLive $ttl -AgeRecord -Name $Name -PtrDomainName $NewHostName -WhatIf
}
# Prompt for confirmation
$confirmation = Read-Host -Prompt "Do you want to apply these changes? (y/n)"
if ($confirmation -eq "y") {
    # Execute the commands without -WhatIf
    foreach ($record in $csv) {
        $zoneName = $record.Zone
        $computer = $record.Computer
        $NewHostName = $record.HostName
        $Name = $record.Name
        $ttl = $record.TimeToLive

        Add-DnsServerResourceRecordPtr -ComputerName $computer -ZoneName $zoneName -AllowUpdateAny -TimeToLive $ttl -AgeRecord -Name $Name -PtrDomainName $NewHostName
    }
    Write-Host "Changes applied."
} else {
    Write-Host "Changes not applied."
}


Thank you Stack and Keith. I will try both of your recommendations and reply with details on the outcome.

Thanks, Keith. Your recommendation worked but there is one thing I'd like to change. With your code it prompts to apply the change after each object it processes in the spreadsheet. Do you possibly have a solution on how I can modify it to process and output all the proposed changes before prompting to apply them?

That's because that is what your original script would have done if it'd worked. :) You'd need adjust the script to first loop through the records generating the -whatif results, then outside the foreach loop get confirmation, and if Y is selected have a second foreach loop to do those same commands a second time, but without the -WhatIf parameter. See my edit above.

Thank you so much, Keith. This worked perfectly and I can now insert it into the rest of my script. I hope you have a great weekend and appreciate your help with this.
